# Attempted import error with "npm run build", works with "npm start"

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, build, nearley

I have a React app that runs fine with `npm start`, but fails to build with the following error when running `npm run build`:

```
`Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Attempted import error: './parseq-lang.js' does not contain a default export (imported as 'grammar').
```

The import statement looks like this  ([you can see the full file here](https://github.com/rewbs/sd-parseq/blob/master/src/parseq-lang-interpreter.js)):

```
import grammar from './parseq-lang.js';
```

The module being imported is generated code from `nearleyc`. Its export portion looks like this ([you can see the full file here](https://github.com/rewbs/sd-parseq/blob/master/src/parseq-lang.js) – again this is generated code, so I'd rather not change this if I can avoid it):

```
(function () {

[...]

if (typeof module !== 'undefined'&& typeof module.exports !== 'undefined') {
   module.exports = grammar;
} else {
   window.grammar = grammar;
}
})();
```

Does anyone know what might be happening or have any pointers to help me debug? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `nearleyc` *can* generate an ES6 module, see the source code here:
https://github.com/kach/nearley/blob/6e24450f2b19b5b71557adf72ccd580f4e452b09/lib/generate.js#L143

According to the section "Using Preprocessors" in https://nearley.js.org/docs/parser
you need to put a line `@preprocessor module` or `@preprocessor esmodule` at the top of your grammar file.

Answer (score 0):

For now I have decided to [modify the export in the generated code](https://github.com/rewbs/sd-parseq/commit/a3426ace6c56da4ead4692ec2c23df4be53046b1). Seems like the real fix here is to update `nearleyc` to generate ES6 compliant code.